# Can I retry file_get_contents() until it opens a stream?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am using PHP to get the contents of an API. The problem is, sometimes that API just sends back a 502 Bad Gateway error and the PHP code can’t parse the JSON and set the variables correctly. Is there some way I can keep trying until it works?

Comment: wrap it in some loop, like `while ($thatdamngatewayisntproperlyresponding) { ... }` ?

Comment: "I can keep trying until it works..." or you get banned and it never works again.  Better to do something different in your app on API failure like: substitute default values, gray out relevant calculated fields, write lock the interface, use the last values, etc.

Comment: Interesting... what it does is it saves a price to my server. Really no default value there, but I suppose I could get the previous MySQL row and insert it again.

Comment: @bishop the thing is, no one can use it, it's only me recording prices every 10 minutes. Will I still get banned? Is that bad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any code it's kind of hard to help you.  But here is one way to do it.

```
$data = null;

while(!$data) {
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json); // Will return false if not valid JSON
}

// While loop won't stop until JSON was valid and $data contains an object
var_dump($data);
```

I suggest you throw some sort of increment variable in there to stop attempting after `X` scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now. I have it running on a cron job so it will take a few minutes to test.

Answer (score 11):

This is not an easy question because PHP is a synchronous language by default.

You could do this:

```
$a = false;
$i = 0;
while($a == false && $i < 10)
{
    $a = file_get_contents($path);
    $i++;
    usleep(10);
}

$result = json_decode($a);
```

Adding `usleep(10)` allows your server not to get on his knees each time the API will be unavailable. And your function will give up after 10 attempts, which prevents it to freeze completely in case of long unavailability.

Comment: Thanks for this. Slightly modified it by wrapping the `usleep()` in an `if(!$a)` - otherwise it was sleeping for no reason if there was content

Answer (score 2):

A loop can solve this problem, but so can a recursive function like this one:

```
function file_get_contents_retry($url, $attemptsRemaining=3) {
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $attemptsRemaining--;

    if( empty($content) && $attemptsRemaining > 0 ) {
        return file_get_contents_retry($url, $attemptsRemaining);
    }

    return $content;
}

// Usage:
$retryAttempts = 6; // Default is 3.
echo file_get_contents_retry("http://google.com", $retryAttempts);
```

Comment: Remember to use strict comparison: if ($content === false). If the response contains "0", then it will trigger a false negative.

Comment: @DenisBobrovnikov brings up an excellent point. In my case, I was getting a 200 status code with an empty string response, and needed to keep retrying until I got an actual response. Your use-case may vary, and may warrant strict boolean comparison on the return value.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, here is what I would do:

1. You have a PHP script that makes the API call and, if successful, records the price and when that price was acquired
2. You put that script in a cronjob/scheduled task that runs every 10 minutes.
3. Your PHP view pulls the most recent price from the database and uses that for whatever display/calculations it needs.  If pertinent, also show the date/time that price was captured

The other answers suggest doing a loop.  A combo approach probably works best here: in your script, put in a few loops just in case the interface is down for a short blip.  If it's not up after say a minute, use the old value until your next try.

Comment: It does, it works just fine. I have it where it records to the database after the while loop, if $lasttradeprice (my variable I get from the JSON) !== 0.

Comment: Well it's nice to hear I won't get banned -- hopefully. All of the requests have seemed to yield a number without reaching the maximum request limit I've set (10).